# Appending Checkbox values to Input Textbox (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have been making a product configurator for the past month and received some awesome help from Stackoverflow. I come back asking for some help. Before proceeding, I have Google'd for answers, looked on Stackoverflow, and tried messing around with the code myself. I am new to coding as well so I am aware that the code is not perfect by any means.

Anyways, my code works by taking an option from the dropdown or checkbox and places its value in an input textbox at the end. **What I am trying to achieve is that in the "Options" section (which are all checkboxes), I would like the value to appear in the input textbox named "completeText" when checked and disappear when unchecked.** *I found some code that worked great, but if I made all of the dropdown selections before "Options" and then checked a checkbox, it would clear out the entire box except for that checkbox's value.* **I need the checkbox value to append to the other dropdown selections. The part number at the end should be all of the values appended to each other, separated by an "-".** Again, I have tried a ton of different ways to achieve this and so far have been unsuccessful. Any direction or help would be marvelous! Thank you so much and my HTML/JS is below for reference if someone wants to help (WARNING LONG CODE):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
<script src="http://www.flexotherm.net/templates/yoo_corona/js/samplepicture.js">        </script>
<script src="http://www.flexotherm.net/templates/yoo_corona/js/options.js">    </script>
<script src="http://www.flexotherm.net/templates/yoo_corona/js/sampleso.js"></script>
</head>
<br>
    <div style="width: 900px; float: left; margin-left: 30px;"><h1><font face="bebas neue" size="15">Design your own</font></h1>
<div style="width: 520px; float: left; padding-right:30px;">
<h4 style="line-height:24px;"><font face="bebas neue" size="6">Heated Sample Lines</font></h4><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<img id="image" border="5" src='http://www.flexotherm.net/images/START2' height="253px" width="450px">
</div>

<div class="choices" style="width: 300px; float: right; padding: 20px; background-color: #eee;">
<div>
 <body>
<form id="example" name="example">
 <b>Series Type</b><br>
 <select id="series" onchange="updateText('series')">
 <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
 <option value="HSL">Heated Sample Lines</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<b>Tube Material</b><br>
 <select id="tube" onchange="updateText('tube')">
 <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
 <option value="E">PTFE Teflon®</option>
 <option value="P">PFA Teflon®</option>
 <option value="F">FEP</option>
 <option value="PE">PEEK</option>
 <option value="N11">Nylon 11</option>
 <option value="S">316 Stainless Steel</option>
 <option value="EPS">Electropolished Stainless Steel</option>
 <option value="CS">Corrugated Stainless Steel (Overbraided)</option>
 <option value="ESSBT">PTFE Stainless Steel Overbraided Teflon®</option>
 <option value="PSSBT">PFA Stainless Steel Overbraided Teflon®</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<b>Tube Size</b><br>
     <select id="size" onchange="updateText('size')">
     <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
 <option value="4/2">1/4” O.D. x 1/8” I.D. (0.635cm x 0.318cm)</option>
 <option value="4/3">1/4” O.D. x 3/16” I.D. (0.635cm x 0.476cm)</option>
 <option value="6/4">3/8” O.D. x 1/4” I.D. (0.953cm x 0.635cm)</option>
 <option value="6/5">3/8” O.D. x 5/16” I.D. (0.953cm x 0.794cm)</option>
 <option value="/8">PTFE</option>
 <option value="4">1/4” O.D. x 0.035” Wall (0.635cm x 0.089cm)</option>
 <option value="5">5/16” O.D. x 0.035” Wall (0.7938cm x 0.089cm)</option>
 <option value="6">3/8” O.D. x 0.035” Wall (0.953cm x 0.089cm)</option>
 <option value="8">1/2” O.D. x 0.035” Wall (1.27cm x 0.089cm)</option>
 <option value="4C">1/4" O.D.</option>
 <option value="6C">3/8" O.D.</option>
 <option value="8C">1/2” O.D.</option>
 </select>
<br>
<br>

 <b>Voltage</b><br>
<select id="voltage" onchange="updateText('voltage')">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="A">110 / 115 / 120 VAC</option>
<option value="B">208 VAC</option>
<option value="C">220 / 230 / 240 VAC</option>
<option value="D">440 / 450 / 460 VAC</option>
<option value="E">12 VDC</option>
<option value="F">24 VDC</option>
</select>
<br>
 <br>

<b>Power Connector</b><br>
<select id="connector" onchange="updateText('connector')">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="A">7 Pin AMP™ (Power Pins 3-5)</option>
<option value="T">Mini Twist Lock (NEMA ML2-15)</option>
<option value="T2">Mini Twist Lock (NEMA ML3-15)</option>
<option value="W">Straight-Blade (NEMA 5-15)</option>
<option value="M">Molex 3 - Pin</option>
<option value="L">LAPP</option>
<option value="N">None - Flying Leads</option>
<option value="S">Special / Custom</option>
</select>
<br>
 <br>

 <b>Sensor Connector</b><br>
<select id="senseconnect" onchange="updateText('senseconnect')">
 <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="M">Miniture</option>
<option value="S">Standard</option>
<option value="F">Flying Leads</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<b>Sensor Placement</b><br>
<font size="1">After selection, specify length from lead or non-lead side</font>
<select id="placement" onchange="updateText('placement')">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="N">T/C Non-Lead Side</option>
<option value="L">Lead Side</option>
 </select>   <select id="length" onchange="updateText('length')">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="1">1 ft.</option>
<option value="2">2 ft.</option> 
<option value="3">3 ft.</option>
<option value="4">4 ft.</option> 
<option value="5">5 ft.</option>
<option value="6">6 ft.</option> 
<option value="7">7 ft.</option>
<option value="8">8 ft.</option> 
<option value="9">9 ft.</option>
<option value="10">10 ft.</option> </select>
<br>
<br>


<b>Operating Temperature</b><br>
<input type="text" id="temperature" onchange="updateText('temperature')" />  <font size="2"> °F</font>
<script>
document.getElementById("temperature").onkeyup=function(){
    var input=parseInt(this.value);
    if(input<1 || input>9999)
    alert("Value should be between 1°F - 9999°F");
    return;
}    
</script> <br><br>

<b>Exterior Sleeve</b><br>
<select id="sleeve" onchange="updateText('sleeve')">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="M">Black Nylon Mesh</option>
 <option value="CT">Adaptaflex Corrugated Tubing</option>
<option value="A">Aluminized Gray Silicone</option>
<option value="S">Aluminized Rust-Red Silicone</option>
<option value="S">Aluminized Black Silicone</option>
<option value="CB">Cool Blue Aluminized Silicone (Premium)</option>
<option value="AC">Armored Cover</option>
<option value="TF">Tigerflex™</option>
<option value="GF">Gatorflex™</option>
<option value="BV">Blue Vinyl</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<b>Port Size</b><br>
  <select id="port" onchange="updateText('port')">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="2S">1/8"</option>
<option value="4S">1/4"</option>
<option value="6S">3/8"</option>
<option value="8S">1/2"</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<b>Port Type</b><br>
<font size="1">Please specify type if "Custom" is selected</font><br>
  <select id="porttype" onchange="updateText('porttype')">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="TS">Tube Stubs</option>
<option value="JIC">JIC Swivels</option>
<option value="SF">Sanitary Flange</option>
<option value="C">Custom</option>
</select> <input type="text" id="custom" onchange="updateText('custom')" />
<br>
<br>


<b>Line Length</b><br>
<input type="text" id="line" onchange="updateText('line')" /><font size="2"> ft</font>
<script>
document.getElementById("line").onkeyup=function(){
     var input=parseInt(this.value);
     if(input<1 || input>9999)
    alert("Value should be between 1 ft. - 9999 ft.");
    return;
}    
</script> 
<br>
<br>

<b>Lead Length</b><br>
<input type="text" id="lead" onchange="updateText('lead')" /><font size="2"> ft</font>
<script>
 document.getElementById("lead").onkeyup=function(){
    var input=parseInt(this.value);
    if(input<1 || input>9999)
    alert("Value should be between 1 ft. - 9999 ft.");
    return;
}    
</script> 
<br>
<br>

<b>Options</b>
<br>
<font size="1"> Please select all options wanted</font>
<br>
<div id="inputs">
<input type="checkbox" id="prof" class="choice" value="PR" onchange="updateText('prof')"> Profiled w/ Data</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="slaveboth" class="choice" value="SL" onchange="updateText('slaveboth')"> Slaved Both Ends<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="slavelead" class="choice" value="SLL" onchange="updateText('slavelead')"> Slaved Lead End<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="slavenl" class="choice" value="SLNL" onchange="updateText('slavenl')"> Slaved Non-Lead End<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="silco" class="choice" value="SN" onchange="updateText('silco')"> SilcoNert® Coating<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="dur" class="choice" value="DR" onchange="updateText('dur')"> Dursan Coating<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="ss" class="choice" value="SR" onchange="updateText('ss')"> Stainless Steel 1/16" Braided Strain Relief<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="thermo" class="choice" value="TP" onchange="updateText('thermo')"> Thermocouple Pass Through* </div><input type="text" id="thermoquant" onchange="updateText('thermoquant')" size="4" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="pass" class="choice" value="PP" onchange="updateText('pass')"> Power Pass Through* <br></div>
<input type="text" id="quantity" onchange="updateText('quantity')" size="4" />
<br>
<font size="1">*Specify quantity</font><br>
 <br>


 <hr>

<center><input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="seriesText" />
 <input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="tubeText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="sizeText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="voltageText" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="connectorText" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="sensorText" />
 <input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="placementText" />
 <input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="temperatureText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="sleeveText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="portText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="porttypeText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="customText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="lineText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="leadText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="thermoText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="thermoquantText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="passText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="quantityText" />


<input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="completeText"  style="font-size:7pt; height:15px; width: 298px; border:1px solid #CC0000;" /> <br> {qluetip title=[What Next?]}<div style="width: 230px;  float: left;">
<div style="width: 150px; float: left; padding-top: 5px;">
<font size="5"><font face="bebas neue"><span style="color: #d80101;">Send  Us</span><span style="color: #d80101;"> an</span> email</font></font></b><br><p  class="tool"> <font size="1.5"> Copy your part number and click the "Email Us"  button below and we will get in contact with you:</font></p>
<a class="readmore" href="mailto:mike.seacord@neptechinc.com;rick@neptechinc.com;brian.church@neptechinc.com?Subject= (CONFIG)%20Temperature%20Controller%20Part Number"><span class="readmore-1">   <span class="readmore-2">Email Us</span></span></a>      </center>

</br>

<hr>

 <font face="bebas neue" size="5"><span style="color: #d80101;">Give us</span><span style="color: #d80101;"> a</span> Call</font><br><p class="tool">       <font size="1.5"> Provide your custom part number and let our dedicated sales staff help you directly by calling:</br></p><font size="2"> <b>810.225.2222</b>  </font> </font>
{/qluetip}
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateText(type) { 
 var id = type+'Text';
 var endValue;
 var inputValue = document.getElementById(type).value;

  document.getElementById(id).value = inputValue;

 endValue = document.getElementById("seriesText").value;
 if(document.getElementById("tubeText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("tubeText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("sizeText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("sizeText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("voltageText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("voltageText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("connectorText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("connectorText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("sensorText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("sensorText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("placementText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("placementText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("temperatureText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("temperatureText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("sleeveText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("sleeveText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("portText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("portText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("porttypeText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("porttypeText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("customText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("customText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("lineText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("lineText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("leadText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("leadText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("thermoquantText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("thermoquantText").value;
 }
if(document.getElementById("quantityText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("quantityText").value;
 }
 document.getElementById("completeText").value = endValue;
}
</script>
</body>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance you can come up with a smallest test case?

Comment: Point of advice, try to determine *where* the issue is happening and only post the relevant code relating to that issue... I know you gave fair warning, but that wall of text is intimidating, and you risk losing people`s interest in helping you fairly quickly because of that.

Comment: You don't need all those `<options>` to demonstrate your problem; move the CSS into a stylesheet (and out of the HTML). And that, really, is just the *start* at minimising your wall of code.

Comment: @j08691 I have a test page going at http://www.flexotherm.net/tester/page . It should have all the options working along with the "Options" selection clearing the bottom input textbox of all the previous selections.